# how to get welcome message in magento from outside php code i.e., from seperate php file

Tags: magento

```
  <?php 
  require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();
  echo Mage::app()->getWelcome()
  ?>
```

Above is the kind of code i am  trying to use.I need to access welcome message and use it in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Suresh ,you can get by below code

```
<?php 
   Mage::app('default');
   echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');

?>
```